# Build WSO2 Governance Registry from source coce

Tags: maven, wso2

i would like to build Governance Registry from source distribution.
I followed the instructions preented in the following link     http://wso2.org/project/registry/4.1.1/docs/installation_guide.html, 
especially the   paragraph "Building WSO2 Governance Registry Using the Source Distribution".

I launched the maven comman "mvn clean install" that start to download dependencies but after some minutes the build process stop with an error. 
Here is an example of the error:
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:governance:
pom:3.2.0 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central 
has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local
 POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]

Here is my configuration:

- OS: Windows 7 64 bit
- Maven: 3.0.4
- JDK: 1.6.0.22
- WSO2 Gov. Registry: 4.0.0

Somebody know why the installation instructions do not work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please use maven2 to build GReg 4.1.1 from the branch.

Use maven3, if you are build the carbon from [trunk](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/).

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: We're trying to build greg from source(downloaded from wso2 site) according to the installation guide.
With maven3(after a lot of time spending to MANUALLY download many dependencies linked to broken repository) we obtain this error 
[ERROR]Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:attached (dist) on project axis2-kernel: Failed to create assembly:Error creating assembly archive docs: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]

with maven2 no errors occours but at the end no executable file was generated for greg 4.1.1
Where we're failing?